# Bootstrap: Interacting with two modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal, lets call it modal A which has a button. When this button is clicked, it opens another modal, modal B. Now there are some content in modal B that I need to copy to modal A, without closing modal B to paste the data to a textbox in modal A.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalA">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalA" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalB">Help</a>
<textarea id="PASTEHERE" class="form-control input-sm" row="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalB" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <p>SOME TEXT TO COPY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: also, typo in title?

Comment: Hope it helps, I didn't feel the need to paste the code because it's not a bug or something. Just wanna ask if bootstrap is capable of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` to do that:

`$("#modalA #PASTEHERE").val($("#modalB .modal-body p").html());`

Comment: Thanks, but the bottom line of my question is, is it possible to interact with two modals at the same time, without blocking each other. In jQuery it is possible but I'm not pretty sure with bootstrap we're kind of migrating the jQuery stuff to Bootstrap....If you try to visualize it there are two modals, both must be clickable... right now it's blocking the other one.. I need not to change it's current functionality.

Comment: @jzoned So you want to copy/paste the contents manually between the modals? Is that your question?